# Using AJAX GET request to pass the value of <option> tags to the URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-select

I want to pass options' values to the URL whenever the users select an option. For example these are the options:

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3

And this is the URL: http://example.com/products

When he selects an option among those 3, the URL changes into this: http://example.com/products?option=option1

I tried vanilla Javascript `XMLHttpRequest` for this, and this is my code:

```
function ajaxFormValidate(_method, _url, _callback, _fallback, _sendItem) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }
        if(xmlHttp.status !== 200) {
            _fallback(xmlHttp.response);
            return;
        }
        if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
            _callback(xmlHttp.response);
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open(_method, _url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(_sendItem);
} //Set a function for AJAX Request
//Actual performance
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var _sort = document.getElementById('sort'), _filter = document.getElementById('filter'); //Get the elements
    _sort.addEventListener('change', function(){ //If the value of the field changes
        var _frmData = new FormData(); //Create a new FormData object
        _frmData.append('sort', _sort.value); //Append the value to this object
        ajaxFormValidate('GET', location.href, function(response){
            //Perform the redirection here (without reloading the page)
        }, function(response){
            alert("Request cannot be sent!");
        }, _frmData);
    }, false);
});
```

Recently, I don't have any ideas for this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Provide a minimal working Fiddle. Also, is there a reason you haven't used jQuery?

Comment: @DavidHope, sorry, but this one is about passing variable to URL, so it's quite hard to provide a Fiddle here

Comment: @DavidHope, I know there are jQuery solutions for this, but I just want to test myself with vanilla Javascript and gain more knowledge about how things work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way of using GET in pure Javascript:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open("GET", "example.com/products.php?option=YOUR OPTION VALUE GOES HERE", true);


ajax.send();


ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {


    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

        var data = ajax.responseText;

        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

And this is the jQuery way **(my preferred method)**:

```
var myOption = $('.your-elenet-calss-name').val();
var myurl = "http://example.com/products.php";
var dataString="&option="+myOption+"&check=";
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: myurl,
data:dataString,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){//Do some stuff here. Example: you can show a preloader///},
success: function(data){

if(data =='success'){

alert('done deal...');

}


}
});
```

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't affect the written function?

Comment: I only provided a working AJAX that sends the data using GET method. You can simply integrate that into your own function.

Comment: I replaced `location.href` part into `location.href + "?sort=" + _sort.value` but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you looked in your console to see if there is any errors?

Comment: @DavideHope I saw it logged out the whole document

Comment: what do you mean by 'logged out the whole document'? can you please provide a screenshot or something else that will show us what you see in the console? also, please provide your edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162167/discussion-between-webdeg-brian-and-david-hope).

Comment: I logged out the document that we specified in the url property